# how $|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}|^2+|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}|^2$ is expressed in polar coordinate

Tags: operator-theory

Why
$
|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}|^2+|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}|^2=|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{r}}|^2+\frac{1}{r^2}|\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{\theta}}|$?
I am confused with the absolute value of operator. I think may be I can use conjugate operator. But I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: Is $u$ complex valued?

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. They are discouraged for technical reasons - see [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233).

Comment: Yes, $u$ is complex valued@lan